# How to translate a html file in assets according to user system language like in Strings.xml in android studio

Tags: android, translate

I have an HTML file in assets, that HTML file have five points of instructions for my application in the English language. I use webview widget to show the HTML page in my android application. This is an offline process. Because I have downloaded the HTML file in assets. So can I use the HTML page in multilingual ways? As we use the string.xml and then we add languages.
If there is a solution or an alternative, I need it to show the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assets doesn't support buckets, so you have to keep all your webpages in assets folder with different names (prefix or suffix maybe?) and pick proper one per language (use `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()`)

optionally you may "inject" language as some value into loaded HTML content and switch text only (images also?) keeping one (or 5 like you have) *.html files. that depends on how do you load this data into `WebView`. `loadData` or `loadDataWithBaseURL` method? make some placeholder in HTML (e.g. `LANG_INJECT_HERE`) and use `String.replace` for passing language before webview load page data (e.g. `htmlContent.replace("LANG_INJECT_HERE", lang)`)